# Multiple processes pushing elements to list STL C++

Tags: c++, concurrency, stl, multiple-processes

I have multiple preforked server processes which accept requests to modify a shared STL C++ list on a server. Each process simply pushes a new element at the end of the list and returns the iterator.

I'm not sure how should each process attempt to acquire lock on the list? Should it be on entire object or are STL Lists capable of handling concurrency since we're just pushing an element at the end of the list?

Comment: basically you'll need to use synchronisation on the list, but to give a reasonable answer it would be good to see what code you have written

Comment: This might sound dumb, but it's for an interview system design question. I wanted to know if we've some form of in-built concurrency mechanism or not. Thank you for the quick answer. (Basically no code progress as of now)

Comment: I would be surprised if there were any standard library implementing `std::list` as being able to be shared between multiple *processes*! They can, however, with suitable synchronization, be used with multiple *threads*.

Comment: Yes as Dietmar says - threading is defferent to multi process - thats why I asked for code. So are you sure you mean `forked`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mechanism for doing this kind of synchronisation between multiple processes requires that the developer deal with several issues. Firstly whatever is being shared between the processes needs to be set up outside of them. What this usually means in practice is the use of `shared memory`.

Then these processes need to communicate with each other with respect to accessing the memory being shared. After all if one thread starts to work on a data structure being shared, but gets swapped out before completing the operation it will leave the data inconsistent.

This synchronisation can be done using operating system constructs such as semaphores in linux, and will allow competing processes to coordinate.

See [This for linux based IPC detail](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/tlk/ipc/ipc.html)
See [This for Windows based IPC detail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

For some reference you can use the `Boost.Interprocess` [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/interprocess.html) which provides a platform independent implementation of IPC mechanisms.

Comment: Unfortunately, I was also thinking of something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8189664/1828115.  Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you meant *threads* rather than *processes* you can share the STL containers but you need to be careful with respect to synchronization. The STL containers are threads safe to some extend but you need to understand the thread safety guarantees given:

1. One container can be used by multiple readers concurrently.
2. If there is one writer for a container, there shall neither be concurrent readers nor concurrent writers.
3. The guarantees are per container, i.e., different containers can concurrently be used by threads without need of synchronization between them.

The reason for these restrictions is that the interface for the containers is geared towards efficient use within one thread and you don't want to impeded the processing of an unshared container with the potential of being shared across threads. Also, the container interface isn't suitable for any sort of container maintained concurrency mechanism. For example, just because `v.empty()` just returned `false` it doesn't mean that `v.pop()` works because the container can be empty by now: If there were internal synchronization any lock would have been released once `empty()` returned and the container can be changed by the time `pop()` is called.

It is relatively easy to create a queue to be used for communication between different threads. It would use a `std::mutex` and a suitable instantiation of `std::condition_variable`. I think there is something like this proposed for inclusion into the standard but it isn't, yet, part of the standard C++ library. Note, however, that such a class would **not** return an iterator to the inserted element because by the time you'd access it, the element may be gone again and it would be questionable what the iterator is used for anyway.

Comment: I take a more radical view about `empty()` -- such a function simply makes no sense in a concurrent container. A concurrent container *has* no size. All you can do with it is *attempt* to retrieve an element, and you'll have to deal with the possibility that there wasn't any element at that point.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I think we are in violent agreement! I just described why it doesn't make any sense to have some sort of internal synchronization with the container interface. When thinking a bit about it is clear that classes with internal synchronziation can only have a "fire and forget"-interface: You throw something at them but you don't care about any specific resulting state, just that something particular happens. A [*monitor*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization)) is the more formal description of "fire and forget".

Answer (score 0):

The standard library containers offer no automagic protection against concurrent modifications, so you need a global lock for every access of the queue.

You even have to be careful with the iterators or references to list elements, since you may not necessarily know when the corresponding element has been removed from the list.

Comment: [Here](https://bitbucket.org/KjellKod/g2log/src/cbe4c5a8bb31dee3459248a55434c76c901454ef/g2log/src/shared_queue.h?at=default)'s an example of a  container, which is protected

Comment: Further to Kerreks Answer if you do indeed mean multiprocess then you'll need to look into synchronisation methods in the operating systems. For example on Linux you need to consider things like `semaphores` (or IPC mechanisms possibly)

Comment: @DmitryLedentsov: Yeah, that works within a single process, but the OP probably needs some more sophisticated shared-memory technology anyway... which actually includes some way to make the standard library list across shared memory!

Comment: i believe that boost has that kind of facility... It might only be a wrapper around the kind of IPC mechanisms I mentioned before however...

Comment: @KerrekSB, [Boost interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/interprocess.html), perhaps